# using greater than and lesser than with timestamps in power query

Tags: date, powerbi, logical-operators, powerquery

I need to check if a timestamp is lesser than a low bound timestamp, or greater than a high bound timestamp. My current formula is this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Correct location", each if ([Time]) < ([Active from]) or ([Time]) > ([Active to]) then "No" else "Yes")
```

Which gives me the error "We cannot apply operator < to types Date and DateTime"

To remedy this I tried using

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Correct date", each if #date([Time]) < #date([Active from]) or #date([Time]) > #date([Active to]) then "No" else "Yes")
```

however I believe the #date function wants me to give it three variables, i.e. (day, month, year) which it cannot extract from the given fields.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong/what the correct function to use is? I suspect I am going to need to extract the day, month, year data and then go with the #date function but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would review the data types on the previous step - one of the two columns must be a **Date**, not a **Date/Time**.  You can use the right-click **Change Type** sub-menu on the Date column to change it to a Date/Time.